# Handling Query string/parameters in nodejs after Okta sign-in

Tags: node.js, angular, express, okta, query-string

I have a angular and Node(with express framework) application. I am using okta for authentication. This angular application opens up with different query parameters for eg. www.mysite.com/home?tab=1. I have setup routes in angular which opens different pages based on the value of tab. But in Okta redirect url has to be static so I have setup the redirect url as www.mysite.com/home. The query parameter info is lost after okta redirects back to the application. How can I get the `tab=1` in node js. I am using `passport` and `passport-openidconnect`.

```
app.use(

      session({

        secret: crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex').substring(0, 20),

        resave: true,

        saveUninitialized: true,

      })

    );

    app.use(passport.initialize());

    app.use(passport.session());

    passport.use(

      'oidc',

      new OidcStrategy(

        {

          issuer: '',

          authorizationURL: 'xxxx',

          tokenURL: 'xxxx',

          userInfoURL: 'xxxx',

          clientID: 'xxxx',

          clientSecret: 'xxxx',

          callbackURL: 'xxxx',

          scope: 'profile groups',

          nonce: crypto

            .randomBytes(64)

            .toString('hex')

            .substring(0, 20),

        },

        (issuer, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => {

          return done(null, profile);

        }

      )

    );



app.use('/mdi', passport.authenticate('oidc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to do another request to the backend in order to get more informatión about the user. This could be useful to get data that determine which is the tab you need to show depending on the user.
Eg: you could send a request to your backend "www.yourbackend/me" and in this endpoint return the tab value based on the session.
Another possibility is to get a jwt with user-data in its payload, however, with this approach you don´t have sessions in the backend anymore.

Comment: The tab value can be different for same user based on from where he is launching our application. There are some other query parameters as well which differ every time for the same user.